# On blender 2.83, my 'enter' does not seem to work?

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut, scale

I saw tutorial saying, press 'S', 'Z', '0', followed by 'enter' to set selected vertices Z coordinates to "ground" (zero).

On my blender 2.83, when I do the above sequence, I see the 'scale' window open with Z= 0 (on the left bottom of my screen) but pressing  does not do anything.  The vertices don't move, their values stay as before.  That 'scale' window does not have any confirm button either so I am not sure how to 'complete' the change.

Is there a mode of some sort that I changed by mistake or perhaps my keyboard 'enter' is non standard?

Comment: If z = 0 then there is nothing to change...

Comment: Enter should work, but you don't need to confirm the inputs that way. You can confirm alternatively by left clicking, which has always been a way to do the confirmation. Right-clicking would instead undo the change altogether. Does it work when you do this?

Comment: What do you mean?  I thought that scaling by 0 meant multiplying all the Z by 0 so in effect forcing all Z to 0.

Comment: I exited blender and restarted it and your left-click works.  In fact I see the change even before pressing 'enter' and 'enter' works now.  So I guess there is some kind of mode that I triggered that seems to reset when you start blender.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Scaling will depend on pivot point.   eg pivot point scene cursor at global z = 0 will have a global  "drop to ground effect"  for SZ0  Remember vert coords are in local space. A SZZ0 will show the local z axis when scaling.